# Heroku - custom SUBdomain

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

My client would like to point his Heroku app to a subdomain of his current website (lets say `example.com` and `subdm.example.com`).

Heroku provides nice example, how to set up pointing from Heroku app to custom domains - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

But how to do pointing from Heroku app to custom SUBDOMAIN?

Should I set up just `heroku domains:add subd.example.com`?

I am rather asking for an advice, because I don't wanna screw up client's website and setup...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've got it right, and don't forget to add the CNAME records with your DNS.